# Deactivate the Touch Event for empty or null text

Tags: java, android, textview

I have an text where i activate the Touch Event. Now i want that if my text is empty or null or there is hint displayed on it, then the Touch event must deactivated.

```
text1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(text1.equals("")){

          }
          else{
         switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
            ic.commitText(textOne, 1);
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
              break;
         }     
    }

        return true;
    }
}
```

But when i touch my text for above specified conditions, it will crash the screen as well as Touch is still activated. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think your app crash because if text1 is null you'll have a null pointer exception when you try this : `if(text1.equals(""))`

So you should try that instead :

```
text1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if(text1!=null && !text1.trim().equals("")){
         switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
            ic.commitText(textOne, 1);
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
              break;
        }     
    }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: My mistake. if text1 is null, setOnTouchListener can't work. So just wrap setOnTouchListener with a condition : if(text1!=null && !text1.trim().equals(""). If it still doesn't work, please post the error you're getting. Is it a null pointer exception ?

Comment: Hey..I did it. Problem is that after this condition, Touch Listener is still activated

Comment: Neither text is null nor text is ""..I don't understand. I put the logger. I just include the hint in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the answer. The solution is this:

```
 if(text1.getText()!=null && !text1.getText().equals("")){
  text1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

         switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
            ic.commitText(textOne, 1);
              break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                 text1.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
              break;
         }     


        return true;
    }
}
```

);
      }

Comment: exactly what i said in my comment : My mistake. if text1 is null, setOnTouchListener can't work. So just wrap setOnTouchListener with a condition : if(text1!=null && !text1.trim().equals(""). If it still doesn't work, please post the error you're getting. Is it a null pointer exception ? Anyway good luck for the rest !